# What is it called when you change the nouns in an idiom

Tags: idioms

What is it called when you change the nouns in an idiom. As an example if I were an artic explorer I might say "Tent Sweet Tent," after comming in from a long day in the cold. The idiom is "Home Sweet Home" but has been changed. Is there a word that would be used to explain that a standard idiom has been changed to mean the same thing but in a different instance. Are there just too few idioms that can be modified in this way to merit a discriptive general reference.

Comment: No, there's no special term for that. Idioms are, well, idiomatic, in that they vary a lot in how frozen parts of them are (not just nouns). For instance, if you change _bucket_ to its synonym _pail_ in the idiom _kick the bucket_ 'die', it's no longer an idiom and it doesn't mean 'die'. But it's the context, repetition, and structure _`X` Sweet `X`_ that identify that idiom, and the `X`s can be swapped at will, as long as they remain identical and fit a context.

Comment: [*Ed and Mai automatically made note of the **mangled idiom** to add it to other choice **Towsonisms**, such as "**Easy as shooting apples in a barrel**"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+mangled+idiom+to+add+it%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl). But realistically, ***Towsonism*** has no currency whatsoever, so I guess you'll just have to settle for ***mangled idiom***.

Comment: There is ***snowclone***, a templatized phrase, which is at least *close* to what you're looking for.

Comment: I would call it "riffing on an idiom," where _riffing_ is derived from the noun _riff_ meaning "a distinct variation: TAKE," according to Merriam-Webster.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Sounds like a Towsonism is similar to a Spoonerism, only it switches words in a phrase instead of sounds in a word (or set of words). For instance, I learned "running around like a head with its chicken cut off" and "killing two stones with one bird" growing up.

Answer (score 3):

I would call it *[adaptation](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/adaptation)*:

> [MASS NOUN]
>
> 1 The action or process of adapting or being adapted:
>
> *oxforddictionaries.com*

*Eskimos might prefer an **adaptation** to igloo sweet igloo.*